# chrome setSelectionRange() not work in oninput handler

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cross-browser, html-input

I'm working with some auto-completion code. `setSelectionRange()` is used to select text been completed in `oninput` event handler. It works at least in Firefox 14, but not in Chrome(6, 17).

Simplified code snippet demonstrating the problem is like this:

```html
<input type='text' oninput='select()' />
```

```js
function select(e){
    var s = this.value;
    if (s.length)
        this.setSelectionRange(s.length-1, s.length);
}
```

I debugged the code in chrome, and it turns out that text has been selected at first right after the `setSelectionRange()` been executed, but the selection disappeared later.

If i bind the handler to `onclick` instead of `oninput`, like this:

```html
<input type='text' onclick='select()' />
```

then both browsers work fine.

Can anyone please give me some clue to make selection work in Chrome?

Comment: It might have been that you needed to call `this.focus()` before the call to setSelectionRange(). See example here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange#Example

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are some problems with your code, namely that the parameters passed into the `select()` function are wrong: `this` will be `window` and `e` will be undefined. Also, using `select()` as a function name within the `oninput` attributes causes a problem because select will resolve to the `select()` method of the input itself. A better approach is usually to set the event handler in script rather than via an event handler attribute.

However, the problem exists even after correcting these issues. Possibly the `input` event fires before the browser has moved the caret in Chrome. A simple workaround would be to use a timer, although this is sub-optimal because there's a possibility the user will be able to input another character before the timer fires.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XXx5r/2/

Code:

```
<input type="text" oninput="selectText(this)">

<script type="text/javascript">
function selectText(input) {
    var s = input.value;
    if (s.length) {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            input.setSelectionRange(s.length-1, s.length);
        }, 0);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This works. I wonder why most search engines' search suggestion only show candidates in the droplist, but never complete user's input and select the completion. Maybe it has something to do with my problem.

Comment: The reason this doesn't work the right way in Chrome (without setting a timeout) is because a Chromium bug that's been active for over three years now: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=32865

Comment: for over a year, I've revisited a piece of code only to give up when it wouldn't work and move onto other things. Such a simple fix...frustrating though.

Answer (score 1):

```js
    
    
    var $input = document.getElementById('my_id');
    
    $input.onfocus = function () {
       $input.setSelectionRange(0, 7);
    }
    $input.focus();
```

```html
<input type='text' id='my_id' value="My text for example." />
```

Answer (score 1):

On Angular for example you can do this:

```
@ViewChild('input', { static: false }) inputElement: ElementRef;

focus(){    
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.inputElement.nativeElement.focus();
        this.inputElement.nativeElement.setSelectionRange(this.valueInput.length, this.valueInput.length);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `setTimeout` does not the best solution. You just need call event handler before use `setSelectionRange`.  i use this:

```
e.currentTarget.value = previousValue;
onChange(e);
e.currentTarget.setSelectionRange(startPosition, endPosition);
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm on React and this worked for me on both Firefox and Chrome. First execute the code for selecting the required substring and then call focus and to make sure it runs last, wrap it in a `setTimeout`

```
onFocus={(e: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    e.stopPropagation();

    const start = 0;
    const end = value.lastIndexOf(".");

    if (e.target.setSelectionRange) {
        e.target.setSelectionRange(start, end);
    } else if (typeof e.target.selectionStart !== "undefined") {
        e.target.selectionStart = start;
        e.target.selectionEnd = end;
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
        e.target.focus();
    }, 0);
}}
```