# move cursor to end of input

Tags: javascript, html, html-input

I have a problem with input and setSelectionRange method. The problem is that I set cursor position at the end:

```
input.setSelectionRange(input.value.length,input.value.length );
```

Cursor moves to end but text stays in the same position. It works in Firefox but doesn't work in Chrome.

```js
var input = document.querySelector("input");
input.onclick = function (){
  this.setSelectionRange(this.value.length,this.value.length )
}
```

```html
<input id="beLowerCase" type="Text" value="______________________________232332" />
```

Comment: Have a look there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11723420/chrome-setselectionrange-not-work-in-oninput-handler

Comment: @Magicprog.fr work same as my example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found easy solution https://jsfiddle.net/r3yohhc0/1/ , property scrollLeft

```
input.scrollLeft = input.scrollWidth;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not a JS issue but a CSS issue.

Instead of setting setSelectionRange, Just add the following CSS to the code.

```
<style>
input#beLowerCase {text-align:right;}
</style>
```

Working code below:
I have added a *class* instead of *ID* as putting styles to classes are a better practice than writing it for IDs.

```js
document.querySelector("input").onclick = function() {
  var val = this.value
  this.value = "";
  this.value = val;
  this.style.textAlign = "right";
  this.style.textIndent = "-1000px";
}
document.querySelector("input").onkeydown = function() {
  this.style.textAlign = "auto";
  this.style.textIndent = "0";
}
```

```html
<input id="beLowerCase" class="align-right" type="Text" value="______________________________232332" />
```

Hope this fixes your issue.

**UPDATE**:

Removed styles and Added styles via JS

Updated the js fiddle link - https://jsfiddle.net/hsbea61b/6/

Comment: updated the jsfiddle to reflect the functionality. https://jsfiddle.net/hsbea61b/3/ . Also updated the answer above.

Comment: I have a onkeydown function.. please check out the jsfiddle url: https://jsfiddle.net/hsbea61b/6/ . You should be able to add further functionality based on this way of implementation. hope this helps.

Comment: Quirk is that with an empty value element's placeholder will also be aligned

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add CSS dynamically

```
text-align: right;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the native setSelectionRange use this function :

```
  function setSelectionRange(input, selectionStart, selectionEnd) {
     if (input.setSelectionRange) {
        input.focus();
        var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !!window.chrome.webstore;
        if (isChrome){
             input.style.textIndent = "-1000px";
             input.onblur =function(){
                input.style.textIndent = "0px";
             };
             window.setTimeout(function() {
               input.setSelectionRange(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
             }, 0);
       }else
            input.setSelectionRange(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
    }else if (input.createTextRange) {
        var range = input.createTextRange();
        range.collapse(true);
        range.moveEnd('character', selectionEnd);
        range.moveStart('character', selectionStart);
        range.select();
      }
}
```

In fact the problem of compability is a **bug** fixed in **Chrome 39**.
So instead of :

```
input.onclick = function (){
  this.setSelectionRange(this.value.length,this.value.length )
}
```

you will use:

```
input.onclick = function (){
      setSelectionRange(this,this.value.length,this.value.length )
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hsbea61b/5/) that I've tested.

Comment: in chrome this work same as my example , because use setSelectionRange.

Comment: Yeah sorry I've forgot the most important part, look at my edit

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand well your need before, look at my edit

Comment: behaviour http://i.stack.imgur.com/6UAPn.jpg for this demo https://jsfiddle.net/hsbea61b/4/

Comment: Yeah that was before my edit but look at it now, it allows you to see the end of input in chrome after click : [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hsbea61b/5/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36198320/move-cursor-to-end-of-input/36198715?noredirect=1#comment60034677_36198465

Comment: It does return to it's initial state thanks to the blur listener.